# How to check if date is in parallel time interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this:

```
TimeID | StartDate | EndDate  | Price
000001 | 03.04.20  | 10.10.20 | 12
000002 | 01.02.20  | 31.12.99 | 13
000003 | 01.01.20  | 31.01.20 | 15
```

For a given date eg. 05.05.20 I want to get the cheapest price.
This Date would fit in TimeID 1 and 2. But 1 would be cheaper.
The needet price would be 12.
Is it possible to group intervals or how can i find the lowest price in parallel time intervals?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post a query.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Hi Johnny, you might want to read about [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), introduced with version 2016.

Comment: It is 20 years after Y2k - NO ONE should be using 2 digit years even for trivial samples and discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
select TOP 1 Price from Tab
where StartDate <= '05.05.20'
and EndDate >= '05.05.20'
order by Price
```

This gives me the lowest price for fiting time intervals.
If there is a more elegant solution, let me know.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did not understand. I was just suggesting that if there is a need for another business rule for ties among date ranges

Comment: @DhruvJoshi . . . Why?  If they have the same price, this will return the minimum price.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh yes! wasn't thinking correctly! OP just needs Price and nothing else. :) Thanks for correction. I'll clean up and delete my comments later today.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 * from table_name where date> startdate and date <enddate order by price
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler query is to use the min function, that returns the lowest value on the selected records (interval).

```
select min(Price) from Tab where '05.05.20' between StartDate and EndDate
```

I've also used the between operator to simplify a couple of conditions xx >= aa and xx <= bb

Comment: I belive the MIN() give a better performance then the "order by". Am I right?

Comment: @JohnnySpindler I don't think that it would be a noticeable difference. The engine should use the same execution plan for both. I only added the answer to give you more options, and also because the query is a bit simpler syntactically, but the execution should be the same.